# Startup script logs location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04, gcloud

In Google Cloud Platform's Ubuntu 16.04.1 instance, the output of my startup script was written to `/var/log/startupscript.log`.

Since they upgraded to `16.04.02` I can't find the logs anymore.

Any idea?

Answer (score 36):

The correct answer (by now) is to use journalctl:

```
sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service
```

You can re-run a startup script like this:

```
sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup
```

See also: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux

Comment: I had to pass the argument `google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup`

Comment: It seems they updated. I will edit the answer so it stays valid.

Answer (score 31):

> UPDATE from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript):

Startup script output is written to the following log files:

- CentOS and RHEL: `/var/log/messages`
- Debian: `/var/log/daemon.log`
- Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, and 16.10: `/var/log/syslog`
- SLES 11 and 12: `/var/log/messages`

Comment: do you know how to send these logs to Google Cloud Logging?

Comment: I have never tried it, but for sure you can configuring the stackdriver agent https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#streaming_logs_from_additional_inputs

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I just had to add `curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging-agent.sh
sudo bash install-logging-agent.sh` to the top of the start up script.

Answer (score 0):

To rerun your startup script, run below command

```html
sudo google_metadata_script_runner startup
```

To view output of startup script

```html
sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to search for the log file probably a lot more but i know the below.

1. `locate -i startupscript.log` - you may need to update your indexes periodically for this option to be optimal.
2. From root  `find / -iname startupscript.log -print` .

Comment: I actually tried this, but there is no script with that name anymore and I have checked all files showing up through `find / -iname *.log -print`

Comment: I read this post about some users missing their /var/log/journal directory after they upgraded which is where their boot log information should be going.  Granted they didnt state that they were on a Google Cloud platform so it could be different.
[Link to Ask Ubuntu Form post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts)